# Prevent an internal Function execution stopping the main execution

Tags: javascript, jscript, internal, wsh

#### background

I have a `JScript` script running under `WSH`.

The script is fairly simple. It iterates over a list of strings, each string, a `JScript` itself, and run each "internal" script.

#### Problem

It is possible that some "internal" script, may call [Quit method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0fx1aw(v=vs.84).aspx). This causes the main script to stop, which is **not** desired.

#### Simple example

```
var strSomeScript = "WScript.Quit(1)";

var F = new Function(strSomeScript);
var exitCode = (F)();

WScript.Echo("Continue doing more things...");
```

the last line will not be executed since the "internal" script stops the execution.

#### Question

If I have no control over the content of the "internal" scripts, how can I prevent them from breaking my main flow.

#### Requirements

I need to run each "internal" script, wait for it to finish and store its exit code.

Comment: Can you spawn a subprocess instead of `eval`ing the thing directly?

Comment: If you have no control over the content, and don't trust the author, you shouldn't run the scripts at all. There's always a way to mess up, and much worse than just quitting.

Comment: @Bergi perhaps the "*having no control*" statement is a bit immoderate. I absolutely trust the authors but instead of enforcing the authors NOT to use `Quit`, I wish to cope with it on my side.

Comment: @Bergi not sure if I know how to *spawn a subprocess*

Comment: @idanshmu: `var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); WshShell.Run("wscript.exe foo.js");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only to prevent specifically `WScript.Quit` calls you can simply sanitize your input with a simple replace. (*) If you want to be able to prevent any way of stopping the script - for example, `var x = WScript; x.Quit();` - you're basically trying to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which I hear is kind of hard.

If you were using regular JS you could have tried something like:

```
WScript.Quit = function(e) {
    // Assume there's something reasonable to put here
};
```

or:

```
var __WScript = WScript;
WScript = { ConnectObject: function(obj, pref) { __WScript.ConnectObject(obj, pref); },
            CreateObject: function(progid, pref) { __WScript.CreateObject(obj, pref); },
            ... };
```

But the `WScript` object doesn't implement `IDIspatchEx` etc. so that won't work.

The only way do make sure an arbitrary string, when interpreted as JavaScript code, doesn't end your script is not to `eval` that string as part of your script, but rather run it in a brand new context. (And calling the `Function` contrcutor on that string and then calling the resulting object is pretty much the same as `eval`ing it.)

You can write it to a file and execute `wscript.exe` with this file as argument, or use the Microsoft Script Control if you don't want to write a file to disk and/or want to give the script access to objects from the parent script.

---

(*) Not that this makes any sense either way. Lets even say that your only problem is `WScript.Quit`. What are you going to put instead? `return`? That's not going to cut it:

```
function bar(a) {
    if (Pred(a)) {
        WScript.Quit(123);
    }
    return 456;
}

function foo() {
    var x = bar(789);
    if (!x) {
        DoSomethingBad();
    }
}

foo();
```

A script that used to end silently now does something bad. If you "know" that changing the `WScript.Quit` to `return` doesn't do anything bad you should also know that there aren't any `WScript.Quit`s in the code in the first place.

There's simply nothing sensible you can do instead quitting even if you could catch every call to `WScript.Quit`.